# Fuse lists created in each thread of parallel for each

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I'm trying to find a way to parallel a nested for loop of a list. In this nested loop, I take each element of the list and compare it with the each other elements of the same list. The elements are 3D objects.

If 2 elements are in conflict, I add the conflict in a list of conflict. I would like to know if there is a way to create a parallel for loop and in each thread they will build a list. Then at the end of the parallel loop, I fuse all the lists together to use it later.

here a sample of the code in sequential loop. The verifications are too big. I hope you will be able to understand the sample

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstComponents.Count; i++)
        {
            Element iComponent = lstComponents.ElementAt(i);
            for (int j = i + 1; j < lstComponents.Count; j++)
            {
                Element jOtherComponent = lstComponents.ElementAt(j);
                [multiple verification...]
                if(hasConflict)
                    listConflicts.add(conflict)
            }
} return listConflicts;
```

Thank you

Comment: You should basically never use `ElementAt`, it's the worst possible way to access an item in a list.  Use the list indexer to get an item by index.  That said, you shouldn't be comparing every single combination of items to look for conflicts.  Rather than using an inefficient algorithm and trying to fix the problem with parallelism, use a more efficient algorithm that doesn't require so many comparisons.

Comment: @Servy I'm still trying to find a better way. Each element can be place anyware in the room. So, I need to make sure their bounding box are not in conclict

Comment: Collision detection isn't exactly a novel problem.  There's lots of resources out there on the topic, as well as existing libraries and solutions such that you don't need to implement something like this from scratch in the first place.

Comment: @Servy - `ElementAt` is fine if the underlying source has an indexer. It's optimised for that access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the parallelization using [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) ([`AsParallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel)). Example:

```
List<(int, int)> conflicts = Partitioner.Create(lstComponents, loadBalance: true)
    .AsParallel()
    .SelectMany((element, i) =>
    {
        return GetConflicts();
        IEnumerable<(int, int)> GetConflicts()
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < lstComponents.Count; j++)
            {
                if (HasConflict(element, lstComponents[j]))
                {
                    yield return (i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .ToList();
```

In the example above, it is parallelized the comparison of each element with all the other elements that follow it in the `lstComponents`. Each conflict is represented by a [`ValueTuple<int, int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2), containing the indices of the conflicting elements. Instead of creating a sub list with the conflicts, an [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators) is used instead, and the fusing of the `IEnumerable<(int, int)>` sequences is delegated to the [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.selectmany) PLINQ operator.

If you care about the order of the results, you can chain an `.AsOrdered()` after the `.AsParallel()`.

You could also do the same with the `Parallel` class, and probably even more efficiently, but the PLINQ is more convenient. So IMHO it makes sense to experiment with the PLINQ first, in order to see quickly if the parallelization offers any benefit in your scenario.

---

**Update:** In this scenario it is important to use a load-balanced partitioner, because PLINQ uses a [range partitioner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl#kinds-of-partitioning) by default for `List<T>` sources, which assumes that the workload is balanced. In this case there is a lot more work to do for the elements near the start of the list than for the elements towards the end of the list, so most likely the default partitioning will result in poor performance.

The [`Partitioner.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create)`(source, loadBalance: true)` will do a good job at keeping your threads busy, but if you want to squeeze the last ounce of performance you may want to invest some time studying the TPL infrastructure for [custom partitioners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl#custom-partitioners). With a custom partitioner you could split your list statically to ranges with different lengths but equal workloads, by taking into account the amount of work required for each element. The advantage over a load-balancing partitioner is that the cost of synchronization is minimized, because each thread knows from the very beginning exactly how much work has to do.

An implementation of such a partitioner can be found below. It has been tested only slightly, so use it with caution:

```
public class QuadraticPartitioner<T> : OrderablePartitioner<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> _source;
    public QuadraticPartitioner(IList<T> source) : base(true, true, true)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        _source = source;
    }

    // Puts a triangle on top of the elements. Slices the triangle to segments
    // with equal area, and returns the elements that are under each segment.
    // Each segment represents a partition.
    // |⟍
    // |  ⟍
    // |  | ⟍
    // |  |   ⟍
    // |  |   | ⟍   
    // |  |   |   ⟍
    // |  |   |    |⟍
    // |  |   |    |  ⟍
    // |  |   |    |    ⟍
    // |  |   |    |      ⟍
    // |__|___|____|________⟍
    //  ** *** **** ********
    public override IList<IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<long, T>>> GetOrderablePartitions(
        int partitionCount)
    {
        double comparisonsCount = _source.Count * (double)_source.Count;
        double comparisonsPerPartition = comparisonsCount / partitionCount;
        var enumerators = new IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<long, T>>[partitionCount];
        int previous = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= partitionCount; i++)
        {
            int current = (i == partitionCount) ? _source.Count
                : (int)Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(comparisonsPerPartition * i));
            Debug.Assert(current >= previous);
            Debug.Assert(current >= 0 && current <= _source.Count);
            enumerators[partitionCount - i] = GetRange(
                _source.Count - current, _source.Count - previous);
            previous = current;
        }
        return enumerators;
    }

    private IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<long, T>> GetRange(int from, int toExclusive)
    {
        for (int i = from; i < toExclusive; i++) yield return new(i, _source[i]);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var conflicts = new QuadraticPartitioner<Element>(lstComponents)
    .AsParallel() // ...
```

Comment: @AnthonyVG I added some more information in the answer, that you might find interesting.